# Way to remove fade animation when changing brightness? [Like iOS]

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, samsung-nexus-10, screen-brightness

When changing brightness on all android devices I've tried, primarily a Nexus 10 running Rastapop, quickly sliding the brightness slider will result in a smooth fade from starting brightness to ending brightness. This, to me, is a waste of time. I would like the brightness to adjust every step of the way, similar to how iOS has it worked out. (And also my windows laptop)

I would think this would be possible because on my laptop running windows 10, pressing function keys to change brightness has a smooth animation but sliding the slider is very precise and instantaneous.

My device is rooted and I can install xposed if that would help. Any answers are appreciated!

Update: Still haven't found a solution